# Diameters of a nested sequence of squares

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, euclidean-geometry

I have previously asked a similar question on hexagons: [The number of points in diameters defined by a subdivided hexagon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4086110/the-number-of-points-in-diameters-defined-by-a-subdivided-hexagon/4086120#4086120)

So, my question here builds on the following: if we have the total of $n$ nested squares (say we first have a square that has edges of length $1$ and around it a square that has edges of length $3$ and so on, as seen in the image below) on a regular square grid where each edge of each square has been subdivided based on the underlying square grid. Label points on an edge of the very outer square as $p_0,...,p_k$. How do we determine the number of subdivision points that a diameter drawn from $p_j$ for some $j\in \{0,...,k\}$ crosses?

As an example, the image underneath has $4$ nested squares on a square grid with two diameters: the green one goes through the total of $6$ subdivision points whereas the red one does not go through any subdivision points.

[image]

Comment: Define "nested."

Comment: My answer to the previous question is not hard to adapt to this one. Have you tried?

Comment: I have, I tried the method you described using the equilateral triangles, but I am having difficulty with the intuition behind the greatest common divisor here.

Comment: Oh and another thing I have a tough time understanding is the case if there is an odd number of subdivisions on the outermost square instead of an even number. Would the answer still be the same?